# Anywhere I integrate $f_n$, the integral approaches $f$. Is $\lim_n f_n = f$ a.e.?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, continuity

Something tells me this is obvious...

I have a bunch of functions: $f,f_n:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, all integrable. Also, $f$ is continuous.

I also have a family of sets, $\mathcal{G}$ where $\sigma(\mathcal{G})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2).$ (the Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^2$, perhaps sans some sets of measure 0 wrt Lebesgue)

Now the important part: we have that $\int_{S} f_n d\lambda \rightarrow \int_{S} f d\lambda$ for any $S\in \mathcal{G}$.

Does $\lim_n f_n = f$ a.e.?

---

Here is my thought:

Think of this set: $S:=\{\lim_n f_n \neq f\}.$ What would happen if:

$$\lambda(S)>\varepsilon > 0?$$

Then $\lim_n \int_S |f_n-f| = \lim_n \int_S (f_n-f)^+ +\int_S (f_n-f)^- > 0$. But both of these parts must go to 0 by assumption. So we have a contradiction.

Comment: Why the downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to show is false. To see this, consider

$$
f_n (x,y) = \chi_{[0,1]^2} \cdot e^{2\pi i \langle (n,0), (x,y)\rangle}.
$$

For an arbitrary measurable set $S \subset \Bbb{R}^2$, we have

$$
\theta_n := \int_S f_n \, d(x,y) = \langle e^{2\pi i \langle (n,0), (x,y)\rangle}, \chi_{[0,1]^2 \cap S}\rangle_{L^2([0,1]^2)}.
$$

But $(e_{n,k})_{n,k}=(e^{2\pi i \langle (n,k), (x,y)\rangle})_{n,k \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1]^2)$, so that we have

$$
\infty > \Vert \chi_{[0,1]^2 \cap S} \Vert_{L^2([0,1])}^2 = \sum_{n,k \in \Bbb{Z}} |\langle \chi_{e_{n,k}, [0,1]^2 \cap S}\rangle|^2.
$$

Together, we easily conclude $\int_S f_n \, d(x,y) = \theta_n \to 0 = \int_S f \, d(x,y)$ as $n \to \infty$,  for $f \equiv 0$.

But $|f_n| \equiv 1 $ on $[0,1]^2$, so that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere does **not** hold.

I am aware that I am using complex valued functions instead of real valued ones. But one can easily adapt the above argument (use ${\rm Re}f_n$ instead of $f_n$) to the real-valued case.

EDIT: Instead of using the orthonormal basis property, one can also use the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to conclude $\theta_n \to 0$.

Comment: Wow this is awful. Thank you for the response. So I guess my contradiction comes when I say that $\int_S f_n-f \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow \int_S |f_n-f| \rightarrow 0...$

Comment: @enthdegree: Yes, that is one of the problems. Also it is not completely clear how your set $S$ is defined. For even if $f_n$ converges nowhere to $f$, you can still have $\int |f_n - f| \to 0$. To see this, consider the sequence $\chi_{[0,1]}, \chi_{[0,1/2]}, \chi_{[1/2, 1]}, \chi_{[0,1/3]}, \chi_{[1/3, 2/3]}, \chi_{[2/3, 1]},\dots$. It is easy to see that $\int |f_n| \to 0$, but we have $f_n \to 0$ nowhere.